# Using mysqli_num_rows instead of mysql_num_row

Tags: php

**I have searched about problem but i can't solve this code**, I see this error :

> > Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP\www\test\index.php on line 13

and this is my PHP codes :

```
<?php
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
function ip_exists($ip) {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ok");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    global $user_ip;
    $query = "SELECT ip FROM hits_ip WHERE ip = $user_ip";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $query_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);

    if ($query_num_rows==0) {
        return false ; 
    }
    else if($query_num_rows>=1) {
        return true ;
    }
}
if (ip_exists($user_ip)) {
    echo "EXIST";
}
else {
echo "NO ex";
}
?>
```

What is the problem and what should i do ?

*I want to use mysqli .*

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP & MySQL: mysqli\_num\_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli\_result, boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546314/php-mysql-mysqli-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result-boolean)

Comment: Your query seems to be failing. Can you do a `echo mysqli_error();` after the query execution?

Comment: @Carsten so what code should i use?

Comment: People should learn how to debug before posting questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your SQL query. That's why `mysqli_query()` doesn't return a `mysqli_result`, but a bool instead. Run `mysqli_error($con)`. That will give you a description of the error. In this case, you are missing quotes around the `$user_ip` variable in your query. This should correct it:

```
$query = "SELECT ip FROM hits_ip WHERE ip = '$user_ip'";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$query = "SELECT ip FROM hits_ip WHERE ip = '" . $user_ip . '"";
```

Missing single quotes while searching ip, though your query seems to be odd, because you are retrieving exactly the same `ip` which you're searching. In this case why don't you just use `$user_ip` instead !?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove global $user_ip;

The function takes the global $user_ip instead of the parameter passed in the function header

also imo, with or without quotes should work

Answer (score 1):

you have a problem into your query string ..

use **mysqli_error()** function to display error in your code . [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp)

```
$query = "SELECT ip FROM hits_ip WHERE ip = $user_ip";
echo mysqli_error();
$query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

change your query string with

```
$query = "SELECT ip FROM hits_ip WHERE ip =". $user_ip;
```