# query error displaying unknown message

Tags: php

Can you please help me with this error?

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in on line 17

Here is the code,

```
$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id ='$adminID' AND role id = '2'";
$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);
$num=mysqli_num_rows($result);  <--line 17
```

Comment: `role id` isn't going to work in that query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 0):

Your query probably has an error. Shouldn't it be "role_id" or something similar instead of "role id"? Notice the space.

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546314/php-mysql-mysqli-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result-boolean)

Comment: thanks, i am also getting a similar error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in on line 92      $query = "SELECT * FROM users where user_id = '$sendtoid'";
   $dbResult=mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);
  while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)):

Comment: @user3469896 Same thing. Check your query for errors. Or paste the line here so we can check it out.

Comment: @user3469896 The problem is you're using $query instead of $dbResult on mysqli_fetch_array. The line should read while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($dbResult)):

Comment: while ($dbRow=mysqli_fetch_array($dbResult)) {
  
    $id=$dbRow["id"];
 $subject=$dbRow["subject"];
 $message=$dbRow["message"];
  $first_name=$dbRow["first_name"];
 $sendtoid=$dbRow["sendtoid"];
 
  if ($sendtoid > 0)
  {
  //if the id of the user the message was sent to is 0, it means it was an admin
  //so displays admin
 
     $query = "SELECT * FROM users where user_id = '$sendtoid'";
   $dbResult=mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);
  while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)):
  
  $to = $rows ['first_name'];

  endwhile;

Comment: I have tried using your adjustment, but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @user3469896 Hmm, what's $query like if you echo it? To get the final query.

Comment: query echos ok, and the function still does what its suppose to. it just display nasty error message above?

Comment: @user3469896 I mean paste it here so that we can have a look at it :)

Comment: while ($dbRow=mysqli_fetch_array($dbResult)) {
  
    $id=$dbRow["id"];
 $sendtoid=$dbRow["sendtoid"];
 $subject=$dbRow["subject"];
 $message=$dbRow["message"];
 $adminID=$dbRow["user_id"];
 $msgread=$dbRow["msg_read"];
 
 $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$adminID'";
 $result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);
  while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result, $query)):

Comment: @user3469896 You're making a similar mistake. That last line should read `while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):`
You only need to pass $result to mysqli_fetch_array, you don't need to pass your $query to it, as you already passed it to mysqli_query()

Answer (score 0):

$result is almost certainly boolean false, because your query fails as Martin points out. In addition to fixing your query, check for error:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id ='$adminID' AND role id = '2'";
$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);
if($result === false) {
    // handle error
} else {
    $num=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    // keep going as desired
}
```

See man page at https://www.php.net/mysqli_query.
Return Values ¶

Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is invalid, it returns a boolean value of false instead of a resource.  Triple check your query and make sure it's correct.  That should solve your error.