# PHP Sign up form error

Tags: php, html, mysqli

EDIT:

Hi I am trying to build a form and check if the email address is already taken during the sign up process. Currently I am trying this on my localhost. But whenever I sign up it says

> Could not sign up.

Where am I mistaking? PHP code:

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists("submit", $_POST)) {

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "form");
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {

        die ("Database Connection Error");

    }
    else {
        $query = "SELECT id FROM 'users' WHERE email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
           echo  "That email address is taken.";
        }
        else {
            $query = "INSERT INTO 'users' ('name', 'email', 'password', 'number') VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['number'])."')";
            if (!mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
                echo  "Could not sign up.";
            }
            else {
                echo "Sign up successful.";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried researching? There are existing questions like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546314/php-mysql-mysqli-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result-boolean   This could be considered a duplicate.

Comment: I already saw that. I could not understand the answer. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: As in the link above mentions: The query either returned no rows or is erroneus, thus FALSE is returned.

Comment: How do I type backtick on a Mac Keyboard?

Comment: QHarr, I am a newbie. I don't understand you

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69820/typing-a-backtick-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard may help

Comment: Also - unless your using a MySQL reserved word, you don't need to use any form of quotes, so try just removing the quotes and it should be OK.

Comment: I did it. typed in backticks but still gives an error "could not sign up".. the warning is gone now

Comment: Have you corrected `VALUS` should be `VALUES`

Comment: Yes. still no luck

Comment: Change `echo  "Could not sign up.";` to `echo mysqli_error($link);` which should give you an error.

Comment: Here's the error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''name', 'email', 'password', 'number') VALUES ('lucifer', 'lucifer@lucifer.com',' at line 1`

Comment: So you didn't replace all of the quotes with back ticks then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using single quotes to delimit field and table names when you should be using back ticks. If you're unable to use back ticks, just omit them altogether - MySQL field and table names are case insensitive by default.

E.g.:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password, number) VALUES ...
```