# SQL sort by max Column and Inner join multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have 2 Tables which are

```
Papers

|ID | Paper_Code | Subject_Code |
| 0 | 2018/Eng/01|     ENG      |
| 1 | 2018/Eng/02|     ENG      |
| 2 | 2018/CS/01 |     CS       |
| 3 | 2018/Sci/01|     Sci      |
| 4 | 2018/Eng/03|     ENG      |

Subjects

|Subject_Code|Subject_Name|
|ENG         |English     |
|Sci         |Science     |
|CS          |Computers   |
```

I Achieved the following table which only shows the Max Paper_Code per Distinct Subject_Code by using this SQL CODE, which is what i wanted.

```
$sql = "SELECT Paper_Code FROM papers
       WHERE(Subject_Code,Paper_Code)
       IN(SELECT Subject_Code,MAX(Paper_Code)
       FROM Papers GROUP BY Subject_Code)
        ";

|ID | Paper_Code | Subject_Code |
| 4 | 2018/Eng/03|     ENG      |
| 2 | 2018/CS/01 |     CS       |
| 3 | 2018/Sci/01|     Sci      |

Now I want to INNER JOIN The Subjects Table to give me results like this

|ID | Paper_Code | Subject_Code | Subject_Name |
| 4 | 2018/Eng/03|     ENG      | English      |
| 2 | 2018/CS/01 |     CS       | Computers    |
| 3 | 2018/Sci/01|     Sci      | Science      |
```

I have tried this but failed

```
$sql = "SELECT Paper_Code FROM Papers
       WHERE(Subject_Code,Paper_Code)
       IN(SELECT Subject_Code,MAX(Paper_Code)
       FROM Papers GROUP BY Subject_Code)
       INNER JOIN Subjects
       ON Papers.Subject_Code = Subjects.Subject_Code";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` before `WHERE`:

**EDIT:** As Barmar's comment says, qualify all columns:

```
SELECT p.Paper_Code
FROM Papers p
INNER JOIN Subjects s
    ON p.Subject_Code = s.Subject_Code
WHERE (p.Subject_Code, p.Paper_Code)
   IN (SELECT p2.Subject_Code, MAX(p2.Paper_Code)
       FROM Papers p2
       GROUP BY p2.Subject_Code)
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me the error "mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given"

Comment: @DreuDavids That means the query got an error, you should call `mysqli_error()` to get the error message.

Comment: You need to add table qualifiers to the `WHERE` clause. `WHERE (Papers.Subject_Code, Papers.Paper_Code) IN ...`

Comment: @Barmar i did'nt know of this feature it will surely help in the future it says Column 'Subject_Code' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous

Comment: @DreuDavids There are thousands of questions in SO that explain how to resolve that PHP error, and most of them explain that you should look at the MySQL error. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546314/php-mysql-mysqli-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result-boolean?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: That ambiguity problem is fixed by adding the table qualifiers, as I mentioned above.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks alot, all i needed was to do as you said and add table qualifiers to the WHERE clause and also add the Columns i want selected at the start of the SELECT as well