# select sum is not working in php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to sum all the value of a column in php..but it isn't working..

```
$query="SELECT SUM(total_earnings) as `total` from daily_report";
$res=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

echo $data['total'];
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\phplocalserver\www\agents\agent_report.php on line 19

Comment: Add `or die(mysqli_error($connect)` to the end of the `mysqli_query` line to see the reason.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546314/php-mysql-mysqli-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result-boolean?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The problem is not in the query, but in the connection : having a boolean in parameter 1 means that your connection returns false